# QEMU Monitor via Remote Desktop

Tags: qemu

I want to access QEMU monitor from my Windows VM, but I have connected the Windows VM via RDP. When I press Ctrl+Alt+2 , the QEMU monitor is not opening. If I do the same when connected without RDP, the monitor is opening.
Is there a way I can open the QEMU monitor when connected via RDP.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean *without RDP*? BTW QEMU does not support RDP at all, so I guess you confuse how it works. RDP is inside your Windows VM OS, thus it knows nothing about QEMU monitor *console*. When it does work without RDP, you probably have QEMU GUI (sdl, gtk) opened, thus it is QEMU itself who knows there's *monitor* console. And... you can have *monitor* available via `telnet` if you want...

Comment: @Jiri B When we launch the qemu we can provide an option i.e. "-net nic, macadd=<macaddr>", with this I can Remote desktop to the IP of the corresponding Macaddress. Another way is to give "-vga virtio" wherein the VM will launch in the same terminal. So my issue is the qemu monitor console opens up( by pressing Ctrl +Alt+2) in the latter case but not in former. Im wondering if it has anything to do with the option I gave for enabling Remot desktop. Please let me know if there is any option which can enable qemu monitor console on RDP.

Comment: Sorry but you are complete confused how it works. Please read QEMU docs. `-vga virtio` is alias for configuring emulated (or paravirtualized) VGA card, it has nothing to do how QEMU launches the output, you are confusing `-vga virtio` with `-diplay <mode>` option. Anyway, RDP is just inside our Windows VM, QEMU monitor is a kind of management console for QEMU process. See https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/invocation.html#hxtool-3 and https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/invocation.html#hxtool-6

Answer (score 0):

QEMU itself does NOT provide any RDP. QEMU supports following "display" outputs.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --help 2>&1 | grep -- '^-display' | sed 's/^/    /'
-display spice-app[,gl=on|off]
-display gtk[,grab_on_hover=on|off][,gl=on|off]|
-display vnc=<display>[,<optargs>]
-display curses[,charset=<encoding>]
-display egl-headless[,rendernode=<file>]
-display none
```

For some output modes *monitor* console is multiplexed, ie. it could be accessed from the output mode, eg. one could access *monitor* console while having QEMU app running with GTK display mode.

But... QEMU *monitor* could be accessed while using RDP, *monitor* console could be linked to various I/O "devices", it could be accesses via UNIX socket, TCP socket etc... One should understand that access to *monitor* means access to virtualization host, one could open/save files via *monitor*. Probably preferred access method if *monitor* is not multiplexed is via TCP socket with TLS client authentication or via SASL.